# Convert text from HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND into status().isNotFound() in bash

Tags: shell, sed

I want to convert the text in a bash variable i.e. `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` into `status().isNotFound()` and I had accomplished this by using `sed`:

```
result=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
result=$(echo $result | cut -d'.' -f2- | sed -r 's/(^|_)([A-Z])/\L\2/g' | sed -E 's/([[:lower:]])|([[:upper:]])/\U\1\L\2/g')


echo "status().is$result()"
```

Output:

```
status().isNotFound()
```

As you can see here I'm using 2 `sed` commands.
Is there a way to achieve the same result using 1 `sed` or any other simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

Since it involves a lot of new text insertion in the replacement part, the `sed` command can be written in detail as below. Just pass the variable content over a pipe without using `cut`

```
result=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

echo "$result" |
sed -E 's/^.*(Status)\.([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)_([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)$/\L\1().is\u\2\L\3\u\4\L\5()/g'
```

The idea is add the case conversion functions of GNU `sed` on the captured groups. So we capture

- `(Status)` in `\1` in which we just lowercase the entire string and then append a `().is` to the result
- The next captured group, `\2` would be first uppercase character following the `.` which would be `N` and the rest of the string `OT` in `\3`. We retain the second as such and do lower case of the third group.
- The same sequence as above is repeated for the next word `FOUND` in `\4` and `\5`.
- The `\L`, `\u` are case conversion operators available in GNU `sed`.

---

If you are looking to modify only the part beyond the `.` to CamelCase, then you can use `sed` as

```
result=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

result=$(echo "$result" |
sed -E 's/^.*\.([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)_([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)/\u\1\L\2\u\3\L\4/g')

echo "status().is$result()"
```

Comment: @KNDheeraj: You just need to do `echo "$result" | ` before the `sed` command

Comment: I have ran this command `echo "status().is$result()" | sed -E 's/^.*(Status).([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)_([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)$/\l\1().is\2\L\3\u\4\L\5()/g'`

and outputing me `status().isHttpStatus.OK()`

Comment: @KNDheeraj: What is your input? in the question you have provided `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` and now you are testing with `"status().is$init()"` why? what is the value of `init`?

Comment: Complete snippet `result=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

echo $result | cut -d'.' -f2- | sed -E 's/^.*(Status).([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)_([[:upper:]])([[:upper:]]+)$/\l\1().is\2\L\3\u\4\L\5()/g'`

That I had tried, which generates this output:

`NOT_FOUND` which not what I required!!

Comment: Why are  you using `cut`? Just directly pass the `echo` string to `sed`

Comment: That beats the hell out of my 3 `tr` calls and one `sed` `:)` @Inian -- all he is trying to get to is `"NotFound"` in `result` so the total string `"status().is$result()"` is `"status().isNotFound()"`. (which will shorten things a bit)

Comment: @Inian your code works fine but there are some httpStatus like Ok, Created where this fails!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GNU sed (`-r` switch), here's another `sed` solution,
just a little bit more concise, and locale safe:

```
$ result=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

$ echo "$result" | sed -r 's/^.*([A-Z][a-z]*)\.([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)_([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]*)/\L\1().is\u\2\L\3\U\4\L\5()/'
status().isNotFound()
```

An even more concise way of `sed` is:

```
echo "$result" | sed -r 's/^.*([A-Z][a-z]*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)_([a-zA-Z]*)/\L\1().is\u\2\u\3()/'
```

They both are case insensitive for the second part, for example `.nOt_fOuNd` also works here.

And an GNU `awk` solution:

```
echo "$result" | awk 'function cap(str){return (toupper(substr(str,1,1)) tolower(substr(str,2)))}match($0, /([A-Z][a-z]*)\.([a-zA-Z]*)_([a-zA-Z]*)/, m){print tolower(m[1]) ".is" cap(m[2]) cap(m[3]) "()"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
<<<"$result" sed -r 's/.*(Status)\.(.*)_(.*)/\L\1().is\u\2\u\3()/'
```

Use pattern matching/grouping/back references. The majority of the RHS is lowercase, so use the `\L` metacharacter to convert from `Status...` to lowercase and uppercase just the start of words using `\u` which converts only the next character to uppercase.

N.B. `\L` and likewise `\U` converts all following characters to lowercase/uppercase until `\E` or `\U`/`\L`, `\l` and `\u` only interrupt this for the next character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sed option "-e" to concatenate multible expressions.